# How do I make X client untrusted, but with access to GPU?

Tags: security, xorg, opengl, xauth

If I try to make a client untrusted,

```
xauth -f XauthorityU generate $DISPLAY MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 untrusted
export XAUTHORITY=$PWD/XauthorityU
```

it loses access to acceleration:

```
$ glxgears
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

How do I run untrusted OpenGL-using applications? I want this:

```
                       |  trusted   |  untrusted |  Xpra   | I want
-----------------------+------------+------------+---------+------
capture screenshots    |   Yes      |   No       |  No     | No  
    import -window root screenshot.png
inject input events    |   Yes      |   No       |  No     | No
    xte str "qwerty"   
list window titles     |   Yes      |   Yes      |  No     | No 
    xwininfo -root -tree | grep '"'
Use acceleration       |   Yes      |   No       | low FPS | Yes
    glxinfo
Install window manager |   Yes      |   No       |  No     | No
    openbox --replace
Use clipboard          |   Yes      |  no copy,  | Opt-out | unsure
    xclip -out                        only paste
```